# Containers and derived classes

Tags: c++, class, containers, derived

I am in the process of making a very simple game whereby objects (elements Either A or B) fly around the screen, colliding etc.

The only difference between A and B is the color of the object (A = black B = white).

Is it possible to have an Element container container (or 20 elements) to hold 10 A's and 10 B's. I have had a look around, and I can do it if I have a Vector of either type A or Type B but NOT a mixture.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks - and Happy belated Easter

KJ

edit:
There are a number of different characteristics that A and B both have, for example different speeds they can move about, as well as different abilities. E,g A can shoot a laser but B can't. That is why I am using different classes.

Comment: Why don't you make the color a property of the class? Then you can get away with one class only.

Comment: If the only difference is the colour then different types is total overkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ containers are homogeneous meaning you can't store different typed objects in them. However you can store pointers to a base type and use two derived `A` and `B` classes.

However in your case if the only difference is color, I don't see a reason to have different classes. Just have a color property on the class.

In case you need different classes you can use a base class as shown below :

```
class Base
{
public:
// base properties both classes share
// virtual methods etc.
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
 // class A specific methods/properties
};

class B : public Base
{
public:
 // class B specific methods/properties
};
```

Now you can have a vector of Base object pointers these can be either of type `A` or `B`.

```
std::vector<Base*> objects;

A *a = new A();
B *b = new B();
objects.push_back(a);
objects.push_back(b);
```

Comment: And you might want to use _smart_ pointers like `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

Comment: I am confused as to, how I would declare the coinatainer. Would I declare it as an Element?? or as either 'A' or 'B' ??

Comment: See my modified answer, and you should really look into the smart pointer classes after to make sure you don't have dangling pointers and leak memory.

Comment: OK great! THank you so much. I am guessing that it works similar to an array ??

Comment: Yes vector is really a dynamic array, you can access elements with the [] operator as in `objects[0]` is the `a` object.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to store different objects in containers, then maybe:

```
`boost::any`
```

is the correct answer?